# ColdFusion server crashing on hourly basis

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am facing serious ColdFusion Server crashing issue. I have many live sites on that server so that is serious and urgent.

### Following are the system specs:

Windows Server 2003 R2, Enterprise X64 Edition, Service Pack 2
ColdFusion (8,0,1,195765) Enterprise Edition

### Following are the hardware specs:

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7320 @2.13 GHZ, 2.13 GHZ
31.9 GB of RAM

It is crashing on the hourly bases. Can somebody help me to find out the exact issue? I tried to find it through ColdFusion log files but i do not find anything over there. Every times when it crashes, i have to reset the ColdFusion services to get it back.

### Edit1

When i saw the runtime log files "ColdFusion-out165.log" so i found following errors

```
error ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

04/18 16:19:44 error ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Here are my current JVM settings:

[image]

As you can see my JVM setting are

Minimum JVM Heap Size (MB): 512

Maximum JVM Heap Size (MB): 1024

JVM Arguments

```
-server -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/../ -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/../lib
```

Note:- when i tried to increase Maximum JVM Heap size to 1536 and try to reset coldfusion services, it does not allow me to start them and give the following error.

"Windows could not start the ColdFusion MX Application Server on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 2."

Should i not able to set my maximum heap size to 1.8 GB, because i am using 64 bit operating system. Isn't it?

Comment: Impossible to tell what the problem could be, all you've told us is your server specs.  Also, is it actually crashing HOURLY or do you just mean frequently?  If it was hourly, I'd say examine things like the scheduled tasks you have running.

Comment: Exactly as @duncan has said. Tell us what you see in the logs, so that a solution can be derived.

Comment: There must be something in the logs. Check jrun4\logs\cfusion-out.log

Comment: Might also be worth taking a look @ the CF status to see if many threads are queueing up and/or the SQL server (assuming there is an SQL backend) in case there are slow queries causing issues.  As duncan said though, impossble to really offer any useful advice off your description.

Comment: @Miguel-F As you said, I checked cfusion-out.log and I've added my findings in the original post. Please check edit1 and see if you get some clues now. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Simonatmso.net After apending a lot of time, I've just added more details in OP. In fact all my findings so far. Can you please check out edit1 and see if it gives you any clues now? Thanks

Comment: Adam Cameron covered all I would have so check out his answer. Past that it could simply be time to bring someone else in to assist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How much memory you can give to your JVM is predicated on the bitness off your JVM, not your OS. Are you running a 64-bit CF install? It was an uncommon thing to do back in the CF8 days, so worth asking.

Basically the error is stating you're using too much RAM for how much you have available (which you know). I'd be having a look at how much stuff you're putting into session and application scope, and culling back stuff that's not necessary.

Objects in session scope are particularly bad: they have a far bigger footprint than one might think, and cause more trouble than they're worth.

I'd also look at how many inactive but not timed-out sessions you have, with a view to being far more agressive with your session time-outs.

Have a look at your queries, and get rid of any `SELECT *` you have, and cut them back to just the columns you need. Push dataprocessing back into the DB rather than doing it in CF.

Farm scheduled tasks off onto a different CF instance.

Are you doing anything with large files? Either reading and processing them, or serving them via `<cfcontent>`? That can chew memory very quickly.

Are all your function-local variables in CFCs properly VARed? Especially ones in CFCs which end up in shared scopes.

Do you accidentally have debugging switched on?

Are you making heavy use of custom tags or files called in with `<cfmodule>`? I have heard apocryphyal stories of custom tags causing memory leaks.

Get hold of [Mike Brunt](http://www.cfwhisperer.com/) or [Charlie Arehart](http://www.carehart.org/cf911/) to have a look at your server config / app (they will obviously charge consultancy fees).

I will update this as I think of more things to look out for.

Comment: The information you provided was very helpful and finally I was able to get rid of the crashes. Thanks

Comment: Did you track down specifically what was causing the problem?

Comment: Basically, that was my JVM which was crashing, I had to increase its memory somehow. But it was not letting me increase it due to ColdFusion 32 bit. Then I installed ColdFusion 64 bit and increased the JVM memory size, it worked for me. Everything seems normal now.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on ColdFusion monitor in the administrator. Use it to observe behavior. Find long running processes and errors.

Also, make sure that memory monitoring is turned off in the ColdFusion Server Monitor. That will bring down a production server easily.

Answer (score 0):

@Adil,
I have same kind of issue but it wasn't crashing it but CPU usage going high upto 100%, not sure it relevant to your issue but atleast worth to look.
See question at below URL:

[Strange JRUN issue. JRUN eating up 50% of memory for every two hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498172/strange-jrun-issue-jrun-eating-up-50-of-memory-for-every-two-hours)

My blog entry for this

http://www.thecfguy.com/post.cfm/strange-coldfusion-issue-jrun-eating-up-to-50-of-cpu

For me it was high traffic site and storing client variables in registry which was making thing going wrong.

hope this help.